# How can I get a program to stay running on Windows Server 2008 even when I log off?

Tags: windows-server-2008, minecraft

I am setting up a minecraft server on my dev VPS just for fun. I can RDP in and start up the minecraft server, but as I expected as soon as I log off it kills the server since it is running under my account. How can I make a program keep running even when I log off?

Answer (score 2):

Turn it into a service using the `sc` resource kit tool.  Have a look [**here**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

Comment: You can also check this out: http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=42337

Comment: There is the pay tool called alwaysup if sc doesn't do it for you